# Format method in msaccess , giving Unsorted data

Tags: c#, ms-access, c#-2.0, ms-access-2003

i am using below query to get the results monthly basis,like[ how much count for Aug,Sep and so on...]

in the below query if i am using Format() to get the results, I am getting data in below format

```
    MyDate      _count
    Aug           05
    Oct           08
    Sep           03

    SELECT  Format([date],'mmm') AS MyDate, count (date) as  _count  FROM Table1 GROUP BY Format([date],'mmm')
```

As you can see Oct is coming before Sep Month ?? can anyone help.
In my query if i have used "mm" in Format function i am getting correct data, but i am looking for Month Name rather that Month in a number format.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT` and `GROUP BY Month([date]` in a subquery.  Then, in the parent query, `ORDER BY` the month number.

```sql
SELECT
    MonthName(sub.month_number, True) AS MyDate,
    sub._count
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Month([date]) AS month_number,
            Count([date]) AS _count
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY Month([date])
    ) AS sub
ORDER BY sub.month_number;
```